# R programming- how to read in variables with spacings

Tags: r

new to R.

I have an excel sheet which have spacings in the variables (eg. "Item Propeties").  How do I derive a new variable from this?

my code (i cannot use "my_data$Itemproperties":

DFnew <- my_data %>% mutate(
Date=paste0(str_extract(my_data$Itemproperties,"\d+/\d+"),"/2020"))

Comment: hello and welcome on stack overflow :) When you ask a question, don't forget to format your code ^^ also, you don't need to write "R programming" in your title if you use the R tag ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need backquotes to evaluate the column name as is, and within `tidyverse`, there is no need to specify the objectname and `$`

```
library(dplyr)
my_data %>%
    mutate(Date=paste0(str_extract(`Item Properties`, "\\d+/\\d+"),"/2020"))
```

Comment: thanks! is there a way i can view all variable attributes? eg. column name, length, type, label

Comment: @DavidMethodTran You meant the `tibble` is only showing few columns, right?  You can convert to `data.frame` with `as.data.frame` and it returns all the columns to be viewed

Comment: @DavidMethodTran. I wasn’t aware that those attributes were exported in csv files. Are you asking how to hack into the underlying XML metadata in xlsx files?